# OnLocationChanged is never called

Tags: android, gps

I made service to get location changes. But even if I requested for LocationUpdates, onLocationChanges(Location loc) is never called.

```
public class LocationService extends Service implements LocationListener{

    ...

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {       
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {    
    }   
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {   
    }

    public boolean startGPS(){
        Log.d("Debug","startGPS");
        if(gpsRunning){
            return false;
        }       
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,this);
        Log.d("Debug","is GPS provider Enabled: "+locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));
        gpsRunning=true;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean stopGPS(){
        Log.d("Debug","stopGPS");
        if(!gpsRunning){
            return false;           
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        gpsRunning=false;
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("Debug","onLocationChanged");
    }   

}
```

Here is my log. You can see I waited 32 seconds and nothing happened.

```
02-22 20:38:59.565: D/Debug(26614): startGPS
02-22 20:38:59.590: D/Debug(26614): is GPS provider Enabled: true
02-22 20:39:31.937: D/Debug(26614): stopGPS
```

I have icon in system tray which shows that it is trying to get GPS location.

Comment: Are you running this in an emulator?

Comment: it depends on how you are waiting for ... are you using something stupid like Thread.sleep?

Comment: Thread.sleep? It should be called asynchronously as its LocationListener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem. GPS in my phone isn't working. If I use only the network provider it works. Other GPS apps can't get any location from gps too.